# Can a VNET address space be used for NSG source address prefix?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I would like to allow traffic through a NSG from all local subnets (not including peered subnets). As I only have one address space, it seems like the most direct way to do this would be to use the address_space of the VNET as the source_address_prefix of the security rule.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "west01-rg" {
  name     = "west01-rg"
  location = "West US"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "virtual-network" {
  name                = "west01-vnet"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.west01-rg.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.west01-rg.name}"
  address_space       = ["10.10.20.0/21"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "servers-subnet" {
  name                 = "ServersNet"
  resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.west01-rg.name}"
  virtual_network_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.virtual-network.name}"
  address_prefix       = "10.10.20.0/24"
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "dc-nsg" {
  name                = "dc-nsg"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.west01-rg.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.west01-rg.name}"

  security_rule {
    name                       = "AllowCidrSubnet"
    priority                   = 100
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "*"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "*"
    source_address_prefix      = "${azurerm_virtual_network.virtual-network.address_space}"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }

  tags {
    environment = "Testing"
  }
}
```

Per the documentation, this value can be in CIDR notation. However, my example above results in the error

```
Error: azurerm_network_security_group.dc: security_rule.0.source_address_prefix must be a single value, not a list
```

If I switch to source_address_prefixes, which should accept a list, I get this error

```
Error: azurerm_network_security_group.dcx: security_rule.0.source_address_prefixes: should be a list
```

So it seems the value is both a list and not a list. Should this work? Or should I be going about it a different way?

- Terraform v0.11.11
- provider.azurerm v1.21.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Terraform pre 0.12, every variable is a string type by default and if you want to use a list or map type you must use that type consistently as you pass the variable around. This should change in Terraform 0.12 as HCL2 has better support for types including more [complex type handling](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/terraform-0-12-rich-value-types).

To solve your issue you need to either index the list to return a single element which would then be a string or you need to be consistent with your list type.

So either of these should work:

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "dc-nsg" {
  name                = "dc-nsg"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.west01-rg.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.west01-rg.name}"

  security_rule {
    name                       = "AllowCidrSubnet"
    priority                   = 100
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "*"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "*"
    source_address_prefix      = "${azurerm_virtual_network.virtual-network.address_space[0]}"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }

  tags {
    environment = "Testing"
  }
}
```

or using a list directly:

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "dc-nsg" {
  name                = "dc-nsg"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.west01-rg.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.west01-rg.name}"

  security_rule {
    name                       = "AllowCidrSubnet"
    priority                   = 100
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "*"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "*"
    source_address_prefixes    = ["${azurerm_virtual_network.virtual-network.address_space}"]
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }

  tags {
    environment = "Testing"
  }
}
```